# Visual Studio Code include file not found in include directory (Windows 10)

Tags: c, include, visual-studio-code

I am trying to get intellisense in Visual Studio Code. I downloaded the the C/C++ extension from the marketplace: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cpptools and also installed MinGW with the packages `mingw32-base` and `mingw32-gcc-c++`. I added the MinGW `bin` folder to `Path` in my Environment variables.

When I add any `include` statement in my `.c` file, such as `#include <stdio.h>`, Visual Studio Code says:

```
Include file not found in include directory
```

Am I not configuring correctly? How can I get intellisense for C/C++?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

1. First, make sure to create a `c_cpp_properties.json` file in your `.vscode` folder

   **Hint**: Use the Command Palette (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>) and type `C/Cpp: Edit Configurations`
2. Add include paths like this:

   ```json
   {
     "configurations": [
       {
         "name": "Win32",
         "includePath": [
           "path_to_your/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/include/c++"
         ],
         "browse": {
           "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true,
           "databaseFilename": ""
         }
       }
     ]
   }
   ```

Comment: I have the same problem under Linux. The configurations seem ok they point to /usr/include (I am trying hello world in C. But I get the "include file not found" on every include line.

Comment: @Zibri In some cases, you have to add the path to `browse.path` instead of `includePath`. [More info here.](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/842#issuecomment-310722840)

Answer (score 6):

As an expansion to wbmrcb's answer, I found header files under Windows Kits directory:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.10586.0\ucrt
```

Answer (score 6):

On Fedora linux I added the following path where all my c header files lives.

> /usr/include/**

to myc_cpp_properties.json file.

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "/usr/include/**"
            ],
            ...
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using MinGW 8.1.0 and the C/C++ extension from microsoft, this worked for me -

```
{
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Win32",
        "includePath": [
            "C:/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++",
            "C:/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/tr1",
            "C:/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/i686-w64-mingw32"
        ],
        "defines": [
            "_DEBUG",
            "UNICODE",
            "_UNICODE"
        ],
        "compilerPath": "C:/mingw32/bin/gcc.exe",
        "cStandard": "c17",
        "cppStandard": "c++17",
        "intelliSenseMode": "windows-gcc-x64"
    }
],
"version": 4
}
```