# VS code: include file not found in browse. path.?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

IN VS CODE i get the error "include file not found in browse. path."
with an error squiggle under my header file `#include <stdio.h>` 
how can i make this library accessible to my code.

all i have is a folder and a main.c file

Very new to all this, the other answers seem to be out of my depth as im not sure what files they're accessing.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 10):

Very similar problem to the one posed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39430277/visual-studio-code-include-file-not-found-in-include-directory-windows-10), and thankfully a very similar solution.

`Ctrl-Shift-P` will open the "command bar", start trying `C/Cpp: Edit Configurations` until it's the top result then hit enter, this will create a `c_cpp_properties.json` file in the .vscode folder of your current project directory (making this configuration unique to this project, so you'll need to repeat this for other projects). This json file has sections for Mac, Linux and Win32, edit the section relevant to you or all if you know the paths for the other platforms. Each block has a `name`, `includePath`, `defines`, `intelliSenseMode` and `browse` property. The `browse` property has a child array called `path` (which is what we're looking for, `include file not found in *browse.path*`), add the paths to your include directories here, one string each, and remember to use forward slashes even if Windows gives you them as backward slashes.

While the offending error disappeared when adding the correct path to browse.path, I also added it to the `includePath` section because according to the hover tooltip `includePath` is used by the intellisense engine whereas `browse.path` is used by the tag parser. Can't hurt to have both set up correctly.

Comment: I have green squiggles under #include <iostream>. In the problem panel, there are two errors. One is "update my includePath", and the other is "cannot open source file "unistd.h(dependency of iostream)"

Comment: @stdio.h not sure how I can help you, unistd.h is a Linux/Mac header so assuming you're running either of those best to check your `includePath` and `browse.path` to make sure they're pointing at the correct folders _and_ that those folders have the correct files. If things look correct, you can always reinstall your preferred compiler to get a new copy of the STL, unistd.h could have gone walkabout?

Answer (score 6):

Attaching example of .vscode\c_cpp_properties.json file with browse.path which solved my issues with Arduino dependencies

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "C:\\Users\\localuser\\Documents\\Arduino\\libraries\\AzureIoTProtocol_MQTT\\src\\**",
                "C:\\Users\\localuser\\Documents\\Arduino\\libraries\\AzureIoTUtility\\src\\**",
                "C:\\Users\\localuser\\Documents\\Arduino\\libraries\\AzureIoTHub\\src\\**",
                "C:\\Users\\localuser\\Documents\\Arduino\\libraries\\WiFiManager\\**",
                "C:\\Users\\localuser\\Documents\\Arduino\\libraries\\ArduinoJson\\**",
                "C:\\Users\\localuser\\AppData\\Local\\Arduino15\\packages\\esp8266\\tools\\**",
                "C:\\Users\\localuser\\AppData\\Local\\Arduino15\\packages\\esp8266\\hardware\\esp8266\\2.4.2\\**",""
            ],
            "forcedInclude": [],
            "browse": {
                "path":[
                    "C:\\Users\\localuser\\Documents\\Arduino\\libraries\\AzureIoTProtocol_MQTT\\src\\**",
                    "C:\\Users\\localuser\\Documents\\Arduino\\libraries\\AzureIoTUtility\\src\\**",
                    "C:\\Users\\localuser\\Documents\\Arduino\\libraries\\AzureIoTHub\\src\\**",
                    "C:\\Users\\localuser\\Documents\\Arduino\\libraries\\WiFiManager\\**",
                    "C:\\Users\\localuser\\Documents\\Arduino\\libraries\\ArduinoJson\\**",
                    "C:\\Users\\localuser\\AppData\\Local\\Arduino15\\packages\\esp8266\\tools\\**",
                    "C:\\Users\\localuser\\AppData\\Local\\Arduino15\\packages\\esp8266\\hardware\\esp8266\\2.4.2\\**"]
            },
            "intelliSenseMode": "msvc-x64",
            "compilerPath": "C:\\WinAVR-20100110\\bin\\avr-gcc.exe",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++17"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Answer (score 4):

All you need to have is, to check if **browse.path** exists in the c_cpp_properties.json file. If not include this part. It should fix the issue.

```
   {
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/gcc",
            "cStandard": "gnu11",
            "cppStandard": "gnu++14",
            "intelliSenseMode": "gcc-x64",
            "browse": {
                "path": ["${workspaceFolder}"],
                "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true,
                "databaseFilename": ""
              }
        }
    ],
    "version": 4 }
```

Comment: I prefer `"browse": {
                "path":[
                    "${workspaceFolder}/**"
                ],
            },`

Comment: I think  only "workspaceFolder" should be okay also.

Comment: Why on earth are there two separate entries for includePath and browse.path?