# VS Code C #include errors included. Please update your includePath

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

I'm just testing out a C program in VS Code but there's a green squiggly in my include statement.

[image]

This is the warning message at the bottom

[image]

How do I fix this?

Here's the code in non-image form

```
#include <stdio.h>
/*
    this is a comment
*/
main()
{
    char c = 'F';
    printf("%d\n", c - 'A');
}
```

Comment: Add code here so we can take a look at what ou are doing

Comment: I literally just created a new file called test.c and all the code that's in the file is in the image I linked above. The code compiles and runs fine but I just want to know whats the issue with the editor complaining about my include path

Comment: One likely reason: don't compile C code as C++.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37522462/visual-studio-code-includepath Please, add the code and the error as text inside the question, not as link to images.

Comment: The thing is I'm not compiling it as C++ code. I literally just opened up the file and it's still giving me a warning. I installed the windows sdk but I'm not sure if it's helping. I'm using Bash on Windows to compile and run the C code if that adds anything.

Comment: Even if you are not compiling your code, VS Code searchs for the `stdio.h` file in the include path... that you haven't yet specified. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39430277/visual-studio-code-include-file-not-found-in-include-directory-windows-10?rq=1 also.

Answer (score 1):

I have [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57742056/2659307) to a similar question that explains how to troubleshoot the VSCode error message `#include errors detected. Please update your includePath.`

A brief summary:

1. **First** check your compiler path and IntelliSense mode.
2. Compare the "C/C++: Log Diagnostics" output to your compiler's built-ins.
3. Use the "C/C++: Edit Configurations (UI)" if/when you need to set the include path.

See the linked answer for more details.