# #include is not working for C++ and C in VSCode

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I followed very many tutorials on how to compile C++ code on VSCode (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=smUzCvqQKC8 I chose this one) but no matter what I do I can't get rid of the "iostream file not found" error.

I followed steps I found here like [Visual Studio Code include file not found in include directory (Windows 10)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39430277/visual-studio-code-include-file-not-found-in-include-directory-windows-10) , and doing everything I can but I can't seem to get it to work, `#include <stdio.h>` won't work for C either if that is helpful info as well. I also have Codeblocks installed if that is disrupting anything?

Comment: Please read [ask] with a [mcve].  Note that may people will not click on (follow) external links.  Also if the external link becomes broken then the question may become valueless to future readers.

Comment: VSCode is just an editor, not a complete toolchain.  What C++ compiler are you trying to use VSCode to launch?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install clang, the guy in the video just installs the vs code part of it, but not the compiler itself.
You need to download the compiler from https://clang.llvm.org/ (didn't tried yet, I use gcc, but it was the most recommended website for clang)
Then, after following the download instructions, go to systemvariables, and under path, type in the path for the compiler binaries (installation-path + /bin)

Comment: or, if it doesn't work, search for setup/install clang, or use gcc instead